# What is the best car and tuning setup for the career races?

Tags: xbox-one, forza-motorsport-6

What is the best all around car and tuning setup for a majority of the career races? I am a beginner when it comes to tuning setups, but have been playing Forza since the first game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are afraid of tuning, then don't. The game will choose recommended cars for you and pre-tune them for the specific career section you are entering when you purchase it.

Every car in its league is competitive enough that there is no clear cut best, although some cars will have a slight advantage. These are usually the ones marked "recommended"

Comment: While this may be mostly true... I have played some careers already where one car can't keep up with the lead cars even after the upgrades. A fully upgraded class B car, different makes can have different acceleration and top speed.

Comment: And "best" is hard to pin down, IMO, I go for acceleration to get the best lead off the line, my buddy goes for top speed, and we regularly compete pretty evenly for first place.

Comment: Precisely, I like to go for more handling and braking and do most of my overtaking on corners.